# Congruence using extended GCD

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, chinese-remainder-theorem, gcd-and-lcm

$$\eqalign{ x &\equiv 5 \mod 15\cr
              x &\equiv 8 \mod 21\cr}$$

The extended Euclidean algorithm gives $x≡50 \bmod 105$.

I understand now that if we combine the two it implies $15a-21b = 3$ but I don't understand how to use the extended GCD to go from there to finding $x$ and the corresponding modulus.

This is what I am using for the extended gcd computations:

```
def egcd(a, b):
    if a == 0:
        return (b, 0, 1)
    else:
        g, y, x = egcd(b % a, a)
        return (g, x - (b // a) * y, y)
```

From https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Mathematics/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm#Python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the GCD of the moduli is $(15,21)=3$, it is necessary that $x$ be the same thing in both equations mod $3$. That is,
$$
x\equiv5\pmod{15}\implies x\equiv2\pmod{3}
$$
and
$$
x\equiv8\pmod{21}\implies x\equiv2\pmod{3}
$$
If we didn't get that $x\equiv2\pmod{3}$ from both equations, a solution would not be possible.

This prompts us to look at $\frac{x-2}3\pmod{\frac{15}3}$ and $\frac{x-2}3\pmod{\frac{21}3}$. That is,
$$
\frac{x-2}3\equiv1\pmod{5}\tag{1}
$$
and
$$
\frac{x-2}3\equiv2\pmod{7}\tag{2}
$$

Using the Extended Euclidean Algorithm as implemented in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/68021),
$$
\begin{array}{r}
&&1&2&2\\\hline
1&0&1&-2&5\\
0&1&-1&3&-7\\
7&5&2&1&0
\end{array}\tag{3}
$$
we get that
$$
\underbrace{5(3)}_{\large\color{#C00000}{15}}+\underbrace{\!7(-2)\!}_{\large\color{#00A000}{-14}}=1\tag{4}
$$
We can use $(4)$ to see that
$$
\begin{align}
\color{#00A000}{-14}&\equiv\color{#0000F0}{1}\pmod{5}\\
\color{#00A000}{-14}&\equiv\color{#0000F0}{0}\pmod{7}
\end{align}\tag{5}
$$
and that
$$
\begin{align}
\color{#C00000}{15}&\equiv\color{#0000F0}{0}\pmod{5}\\
\color{#C00000}{15}&\equiv\color{#0000F0}{1}\pmod{7}
\end{align}\tag{6}
$$
To solve $(1)$ and $(2)$ we can add $1$ times $(5)$ to $2$ times $(6)$ to get
$$
\begin{align}
16&\equiv\color{#0000F0}{1}\pmod{5}\\
16&\equiv\color{#0000F0}{2}\pmod{7}
\end{align}\tag{7}
$$
Equations $(7)$ tell us that $\frac{x-2}3\equiv16\pmod{35}$ or that
$$
\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{x\equiv50\pmod{105}}\tag{8}
$$

Comment: Replacing $x$ with $(x-2)/3$ is likely too clever and unmotivated for the OP's interests. The OP wants a systematic method. Also, the OP should have linked to their [previous question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1377482/why-is-this-congruence-true).

Comment: @anon: Actually, the process behind getting $(1)$ and $(2)$ is almost necessary in order to solve the problem. Perhaps what I need to do is to motivate what I did to get those lines. Editing...

Comment: How did you get the righthand 1 in (x-2)/3 = 1 mod 5, and how did you get the righthand 2 in (x-2)/3 = 2 mod 7?

Comment: @user2597879: $\frac{5-2}3=1$ for the mod $5$ equation and $\frac{8-2}{3}=2$ for the mod $7$ equation. Note that if $x\equiv ab\pmod{am}$, then $a\mid x$ and $\frac xa\equiv b\pmod{m}$.

Comment: @user2597879: no. Take a look at the end of my last comment. Since $x-2\equiv 3\pmod{15}$, we know that $3\mid x-2$, so the division is actual division, not modular division.

Comment: How did you go from (4) to (5) and (6)?

Comment: (I ask because I am writing a program to do this and I just want to make sure I have a systematic understanding of what's going on. So far I'm good up to (4))

Comment: @user2597879: I have added color to show where the $-14$ and $15$ come from.

Comment: Is there a systematic way to get to (6)? I see how how those four congruences came about, but how do you know to multiply the first by 1 and the second by two (I think the goal is to get the same left term, but aren't there several?)? And is there ever any need to do another GCD check like you did at the start at this point?

Comment: Also it seems like the 1 and 2 never really get used anywhere else from steps (1) and (2). Once you've done the gcd check it looks like you can reduce to moduli 5, 7 and then run the extended gcd algorithm with 5 and 7 as arguments to get gcd=1 and a,b=3, -2.

Comment: I assume you are asking about $(7)$ and not $(6)$. In $(7)$ we are trying to find $\frac{x-2}3$ so that $\frac{x-2}3\equiv1\pmod{5}$ and $\frac{x-2}3\equiv2\pmod{7}$ because that is what we have from $(1)$ and $(2)$. We get those by taking linear combinations of $(5)$ and $(6)$.

Comment: Yes, but is there a _systematic_ way or is it freehanded?

Comment: Everything I have done above is very systematic. Where does it look freehanded?

Comment: Taking the linear combinations to arrive at (7). Let m=5 and n=7, the moduli. I am writing a program for this. In other words once I finish doing egcd(5,7) =(g,a,b) =  (1,3,-2), this means making those four congruences: ma mod m, ma mod n, nb mod m, and nb mod n. Correct so far?

Comment: By systematic I mean something that will apply to the general case and not just this one (the example was meant to help make the generalization easier to understand), because for example you can't always multiple (5) by 1 and (6) by 2.

Comment: Note that we are simply combining the vectors $\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}$ from $(5)$ and $\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\end{bmatrix}$ from $(6)$ to get the vector $\begin{bmatrix}1\\2\end{bmatrix}$ in $(7)$ that we got from $(1)$ and $(2)$. I have highlighted these vectors in blue.

Comment: @user2597879: does this make sense, or is there something still confusing? Should I work another example?

Comment: @robjohn Still confusing but I don't think this particular question is necessarily best for what I am trying to do

Comment: We get $(1)$ and $(2)$ from considering the residues modulo the GCD of the moduli; that is, $x\equiv2\pmod{3}$. We use the Extended Euclidean Algorithm in $(3)$ to get $(4)$. We use $(4)$ to get a number which is $\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}$ mod $\begin{bmatrix}5\\7\end{bmatrix}$ in $(5)$ and a number which is $\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\end{bmatrix}$ mod $\begin{bmatrix}5\\7\end{bmatrix}$ in $(6)$ so that we can easily compute a number which is $\begin{bmatrix}1\\2\end{bmatrix}$ mod $\begin{bmatrix}5\\7\end{bmatrix}$ in $(7)$ to solve the equations in $(1)$ and $(2)$.

Comment: @user2597879 I posted an answer using another method which you might find simpler. There are various ways to solve such systems.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit simpler if we proceed as follows

$\bmod 15\!:\,\ 5\equiv x\equiv 8\!+\!21\,\color{#c00}k\equiv 8\!+\!6k\ \ \overbrace{\!\!\iff 6k\equiv -3\iff\bmod\color{#c00} 5\!:\,\ 2k\equiv -1}^{\Large\! 15j\,+\,6k\ =\ -3\ \ \ \ \overset{\LARGE (\ \ )/3}\iff\ \ \ \  5j\,+\,2k\ =\ -1 }\equiv 4\iff \color{#c00}{k\equiv 2}$

So we conclude $\, x = 8\!+\!21(\color{#c00}{2\!+\!5}n) = 50\! +\! 105n$

**Remark** $ $ [See here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2060729/242) for the general method of transforming the Bezout solution into a CRT solution.