# Prove that $c + \mathrm{lcm}(m,s)\mathbb Z=(m\mathbb Z+k)\cap(s\mathbb Z+t)$ for every $c$ in $(m\mathbb Z+k)\cap(s\mathbb Z+t)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

The inclusion $(m\mathbb{Z} + k) \cap (s \mathbb{Z} + t) \supset c + lcm(m,s)\mathbb{Z}$ is trivial, but I've been stuck with the other one for some time now. I thought about the chinese remainder theorem but couldn't actually apply it. Help?

OBS: Here we assume that the intersection is non empty.

Comment: @Did My original title actually had words, but someone else edited it (and I like it better now actually). Imho, excellent communication requires only that the intended meaning is conveyed clearly, correctly and without ambiguity, and I think this applies here too...

Comment: Words and clarity are not antagonistic... Many student passes by a phase when they think that symbols are more precise, then they grow up (and/or they study the masters).

Comment: @Did I agree with you in general, but in this case I think it doesn't matter. I'm quite aware symbols can often be antagonistic to clarity and then it's better to use words, but for this specific situation I think there is no loss of clarity. I admit I've already passed that phase you mention.

Comment: Hmmm... you are the one who linked words to lack of clarity, right? And I disagreed. But the link of symbols to lack of clarity was not made, so there is no need to debunk it. If you want to know, I would rather invoke *ugliness* here...

Comment: What I meant was that words are sufficient for clarity, but not absolutely always necessary for it. I agree it's ugly alright and I wouldn't let that title up if it was anything any more advanced, but in this case it's not. I think this discussion is meaningless since imo we seem to agree on almost everything. You can rest easy knowing I try to use as many words as I can as often as possible.

Comment: Then why you let the title in its sorry present state is something I cannot fathom (but that you have every right to do, **of course**).

Comment: @Did I tried to think of a reason too and couldn't... so there, problem solved. Thanks for the patience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** $\,c',c\in (k\!+\!m\Bbb{Z}) \cap (t\!+\!s \Bbb{Z})\,\Rightarrow\,c'\!-c\in m\Bbb Z,s\Bbb Z\,\Rightarrow\,c'\!-c\in m\Bbb Z\cap n\Bbb Z = {\rm lcm}(m,n)\Bbb Z$

**Remark** $ $ This is equivalent to the *uniqueness* of a solution $\,x = c\,$ of the following congruences

$$\begin{align} x&\equiv k\!\!\pmod{\!m}\\ x&\equiv t\!\!\pmod{\!s}\end{align}$$

If $\,x = c'$ is another solution then $\, c'\equiv x\equiv c\pmod{\! m}\,$ so $\ m\mid c'-c.\,$ Similarly $\,s\mid c'-c\,$ [therefore](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2322544/242) $\,\ell := {\rm lcm}(m,s)\mid c'-c,\,$ thus $\,c'\equiv c\pmod{\!\ell},\,$ i.e. any solution is unique $\!\bmod \ell.\,$ Therefore if you know [that form of CRT](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/20259/242) then it follows immediately from the uniqueness part.

As explained [here,](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2060729/242) the *existence* part of CRT (solvability criterion) can be expressed similarly, i.e.

$$  {k\! +\! m\Bbb Z\,\cap\, t\! +\! s\Bbb Z \neq \phi \iff k-t \in m\Bbb Z+s\Bbb Z = \gcd(m,s)\Bbb Z}\qquad $$