# I need a modular arithmetic theorem or method

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I only need a theorem or method to solve the problem (if exists).

With this data and having the real value of all the data marked as letter EXCEPT "Y":

```
X ≡ a (mod b)
X ≡ c (mod d)
Y ≡ a (mod b)
Y ≡ c (mod d)
Z ≡ a (mod b)
Z ≡ c (mod d)
```

I need to find "Y". I know that "Y" is a number between X and Z. 
"B" and "D" are prime numbers.
The numbers are very big, so I need a procedure to simplify the problem.

Thanks.

Comment: Look into the [chinese remainder theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem).

Comment: You do know that $X\equiv Z\pmod{bd}$? So how is $Y$ between them?

Comment: @DonThousand $Y=X+2bd, Z=X+5bd$ for instance works fine...

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Of course I know you can do that, but the way it is phrased, it seem as though $X<Y<Z$ is given by the equivalences.

Comment: @DonThousand Hrm; I can see where you're coming from, but I just took $X\lt Y\lt Z$ as another piece of information the user starts with, rather than something that they've derived from the equalities.

Comment: Thanks for everyone, was =+ and =+2.
Sorry if the question was too obvious.

Comment: @user3066261 In essence, $bd\mid Y-X,Z-Y$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $\ x,y,z\,$ are all solutions of the same system of congruences, which, [by CRT,](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3091346/242) if solvable has solutions unique $\!\bmod \ell = {\rm lcm}(b,d),\,$ so if $\,x\le y\le z\,$ then $\, y = x + n\ell\,$ for all $\,n\ge 0,\,$  $\,y\le z$