# Prob. 15, Sec. 1.3, in Herstein's TOPICS IN ALGEBRA 2nd ed: If $(m, n)=1$, then, given $a$ and $b$, there is an $x$ such that

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, modular-arithmetic, gcd-and-lcm

Here is Prob. 15, Sec. 3, in the book *Topics in Algebra* by I.N. Herstein, 2nd edition:

> If $(m, n) = 1$, given $a$ and $b$, prove that there exists an $x$ such that $x \equiv a \mod m$ and $x \equiv b \mod n$.

[ Here $(m, n)$ denotes the Greatest Common Divisor (GCD) of the positive integers $m$ and $n$. ]

My Attempt:

> We note that there is an integer $x$ such that $x \equiv a \mod m$ and $x \equiv b \mod n$ if and only if we have $m | (x-a)$ and $n | (x-b)$, which is the case if and only if there are integers $p$ and $q$ such that $x-a = mp$ and $x-b =nq$, and hence 
>   $$ a + mp = b +nq, $$
>   which holds if and only if
>   $$ mp - nq = b-a. \tag{1}$$
>
> Now as $(m, n) = 1$, so by Lemma 1.3.1 in Herstein there exist integers $r$ and $s$ such that 
>   $$ mr + ns = 1, $$
>   and hence
>   $$ mr(b-a) + ns(b-a) = b-a. \tag{2} $$
>
> Comparing (1) and (2) above, we find that if we put 
>   $$ x \colon= a + mr(b-a) = b - ns(b-a), $$
>   then our desired conditions hold.

Is this proof correct? If so, is it rigorous enough for Herstein? If not, then where are the issues?

Comment: Yes, this is a [common Bezout-based proof.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2060729/242)