# Compute $2^{1990}\bmod 1990,\,$ e.g. using CRT

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, contest-math, problem-solving

Find the remainder when $2^{1990}$ is divided by $1990$.

I have obtained that $2^{1990}\equiv{29}\pmod{199}$ and $2^{1990}\equiv{4}\pmod{10}$ but I am unable to proceed after this. So how can we proceed the given problem?

Comment: By the Chinese Remainder Theorem, there is a unique remainder modulo $1990$ which is $29 \bmod{199}$ and $4 \bmod{10}$. You can find this remainder using the Euclidean algorithm.

Comment: I am sorry I would like to get an answer without the use of Chinese remainder theorem @Haran. But thank you for the idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You know that there exist $m,n$ such that $$2^{1990}=199m+29=10n+4.$$ This gives you the equation $$\tag1199m-10n=25.$$ As $199$ and $10$ are coprime, we can see that $199\times(-1)+10\times20=1$. Hence $$199\times(-25)+10\times500=25.$$ So the solutions to $(1)$ are of the form
$$
m=-25+10k,\qquad\qquad n=500+199k,\qquad\qquad k\in\mathbb Z.
$$
Then
$$
2^{1990}=10n+4=10(500+199k)+4=5004+1990k.
$$
This tells us that
$$
2^{1990}\equiv 5004\pmod{1990}=1024\pmod{1990}.
$$

Comment: **Note** This answer is a special case of a well-known Bezout-based CRT solution method, which is described in *many* prior answers, e.g. see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2060729/242).

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242.)
It's best for site health to delete this answer (which also minimizes community time wasted on dupe processing).